# Understandin kernel, image and cokernel of a map

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve the following problem: a $7$ by $15$ matrix of integers determines a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^{15} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{7}$. Assume that all $6$ by $6$ minors of the matrix vanish and that all of the $5$ by $5$ minors are divisible by $8$ and one of these is equal to $8$. Describe as completely as possible a) the kernel b) the image and c) the cokernel of $\phi$.

I really have no formal idea of how to solve it. Intuitively, I think the answers for the kernel should that kernel has dimension $10$, so isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{10}$, the image should have dimension $5$ and so isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^5$. However, I really have no idea how to attack the cokernel part and don't know how to formally argue for my intuition. Can anybody help me with this?

Some solutions I found say that by elementary row and column operations, such a matrix can be reduced to a matrix with five positive entries down its diagonal, with all other entries $0$, and the product of these five positive entries is $8$ (the ideal generated by the $5$ by $5$ minors is unchanged by these elementary operations and it is $(8)$) . However, I don't understand why we can do such elementary row and columns transformations and how the ideal of the minors come into play. Can anybody explain this solution? Or have some reference to read more about this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the last paragraph, look up *Smith normal form*.

Comment: If all the $\mathbb{Z}$s were instead $\mathbb{Q}$s, then I think the 6 by 6 minors part would say that your matrix has rank strictly less than 6, and the 5 by 5 part would say that your matrix has rank at least 5.  I think you're right about the kernel (I would use "rank" instead of "dimension").  My guess is that the kernel and image parts will be easier than the cokernel part, since I think the kernel and image have to be free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules but the cokernel doesn't have to be.

Comment: To answer the question about the cokernel, lookup presentation matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!!